# Ubuntu Crashed my Windows recovery

Tags: windows, ubuntu, laptop

I have `Windows 8.1` installed Laptop. I wanted to install Ubuntu on my laptop. So, Inserted `ubuntu` bootable pen drive. It initiated a dark red screen like this: [image: Dark Screen] and nothing happened for more two hours. Then I forcefully stopped my laptop.

I restarted my laptop and tried to reinstall windows with these steps. `Settings >Change PC Settings >Update and Recovery >Recovery >Remove everything and reinstall windows >Get Started`. Then Windows has thrown error `could not find recovery environment`. But now there is a virus in my system and I need to reset my laptop using `Windows RE`.

Here is my diskpart list:

```
DISKPART> list volume

Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition     99 GB  Healthy    Boot
Volume 2     E   Entertainme  NTFS   Partition    200 GB  Healthy
Volume 3     F   Important    NTFS   Partition    141 GB  Healthy
Volume 4         Windows RE   NTFS   Partition   1474 MB  Healthy    Hidden
Volume 5                      FAT32  Partition    260 MB  Healthy    System
Volume 6                      NTFS   Partition    450 MB  Healthy    Hidden
Volume 7                      NTFS   Partition    350 MB  Healthy    Hidden
Volume 8         Recovery     NTFS   Partition     22 GB  Healthy    Hidden
```

and in my `C:\Windows\System32\Recovery` directory, there are only two files :

```
Directory: C:\Windows\system32\Recovery


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        05-04-2014     05:14       1064 ReAgent.xml
-a---        02-03-2014     02:00        993 ReAgent_Merged.xml1
```

Please help me to recover it.

Comment: What makes you think there is a virus on your system?

Comment: @Ramhound- adds by "RadStroids" are appearing in any browser everywhere in any web page. I tried windows defender to scan but it could not detect.   I followed instructions given here http://malwaretips.com/blogs/radsteroids-virus-removal/. but it works only for one or two sessions only. after that it returns back again.

Comment: Windows defender isn't designed to find nagware or adware try malwarebytes let's solve one problem at a time

Comment: @Ramhound :Thanks forr the suggestion. I am able to remove it using quick heal antivirus. But however windows RE must be accessible for future recovery purpose. So kindly help me to recover that :)

Comment: You can use DISM to repair most problems provided you can boot into Windows ( which it sounds like you can ) since you removed the adware.